# Constantly lag in opengl application

Tags: c++, winapi, opengl, lag

I'm getting some repeating lags in my opengl application.
I'm using the win32 api to create the window and I'm also creating a 2.2 context.
So the main loop of the program is very simple:

- Clearing the color buffer
- Drawing a triangle
- Swapping the buffers.

The triangle is rotating, that's the way I can see the lag.
Also my frame time isn't smooth which may be the problem.
But I'm very very sure the delta time calculation is correct because I've tried plenty ways.

Do you think it could be a graphic driver problem?
Because a friend of mine run almost the exactly same program except I do less calculations + I'm using the standard opengl shader.
Also, His program use more CPU power than mine and the CPU % is smoother than mine.

I should also add:
On my laptop I get same lag every ~1 second, so I can see some kind of pattern.

Comment: Do you have a sleep statement in your code? Try increasing the duration of the sleep statement, and increasing the amount of rotation per iteration.

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons for a jittery frame rate.  Off the top of my head:

- Not calling glFlush() at the end of each frame
- other running software interfering
- doing things in your code that certain graphics drivers don't like
- bugs in graphics drivers
- Using the standard windows time functions with their terrible resolution

Try these:

- kill as many running programs as you can get away with.  Use the process tab in the task manager (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>ESC</kbd>) for this.
- bit by bit, reduce the amount of work your program is doing and see how that affects the frame rate and the smoothness of the display.
- if you can, try enabling/disabling vertical sync (you may be able to do this in your graphic card's settings) to see if that helps
- add some debug code to output the time taken to draw each frame, and see if there are anomalies in the numbers, e.g. every 20th frame taking an extra 20ms, or random frames taking 100ms.

Comment: Don't forget, in the case of hardware rendering, taking up all the CPU time in your main loop polling for input & waiting for the new frame. Graphics drivers need CPU too.

Comment: glFlush is implied by SwapBuffers, no need to call it on a double buffered context.

Comment: Thank you. I'm now printing out the frame time in ms, but just when ms > 10.0f. I get some interesting results. When my rotating triangle glitch lag the ms is around 17-32(often ~30). The frame time is around 3 ms when it's running smooth, I've not tested how long time it's taking between the lag sikes yet, but do you have any idea of what the problem could be?

Comment: like I said, it could be *anything*.  There could be another program on your laptop interfering, or it could be a bug in the driver, or it could be just your program.  As I suggested, try changing your program, and killing other running processess, and see how that affects the frame draw times.

Comment: Also try *not* filtering out times < 10.0f, just to see how often lag happens.

Comment: I think I fixed the lag in some way, hmm. But also it may have to do with my monitor actually! Because when I change the color depth from 32 to 16 it's not lagging and when I change it bad to 32 it's keeping lagging. Any idea why? Is this the actual reason why it's not so smooth sometimes, Becuase it seems pretty random. Could it be  interference on the monitor cable? Not programming related but interesting anyway!

Comment: Monitors don't behave like that.  It sounds very much like a graphics card driver issue, possibly exasperated by whatever is currently running on your machine.